# Save specific value in first list and last list to SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, android-listview

I have a listView as image below.

[image]

When the submit `button` is clicked, I want the `Time In` in the first row and `Time Out` in the second row saved into **Time table**. It is possible to achive ?

**TimeTable**

```
------------------------
| PK |Time In  |Time Out|
| -= |---------|--------|
|  1 |  9:0    | 18:0   |
|    |         |        |
```

Comment: What is the format of time you are storing in DB

Comment: @Clairvoyant I'm using `timePick dialog`

Comment: guys please leave your comment or answer here instead of give a downvotes only :)

Comment: store it as string in sqlite, just get the value from your list as string and save it in db

Comment: How I know which value is in the first list or last? Since all the variable are same

Comment: @John- All variable means john dont understand that

Comment: Let say this is the code in A. `btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // sumbit button is clicked public void onClick(View arg0) { TimeRecord.insertTime(a1, W1); } } );`

Comment: how can I indicate that `a1` is **first list** time in, `W1` is **last list** time out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert time to int and than save into `sqlite`, for example:

```
Store : 14:30  ===> 14 * 60 + 30 ===> 870

Read : 870 ===> hour= 870 / 60; minute = 870 % 60; ===> String time=hour+":"+minute;
```

Database:

```
public class Database {

private TimesHelper mHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

public Database(Context context) {

    this.mHelper = new TimesHelper(context);
    this.mDatabase = this.mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void insertTimes(int timeIn, int timeOut){

    String sql = "INSERT INTO TimeTable VALUES (?,?,?);";

    SQLiteStatement statement = this.mDatabase.compileStatement(sql);
    this.mDatabase.beginTransaction();

    statement.clearBindings();

    statement.bindString(2, timeIn);
    statement.bindLong(3, timeOut);     

    statement.execute();        

    this.mDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful();
    this.mDatabase.endTransaction();
}

public String getAllTimeTable(){

    //get a list of columns to be retrieved, we need all of them
    String[] columns = {
            "ID",
            "TimeIn",
            "TimeOut"                
    };

    Cursor cursor = this.mDatabase.query("TimeTable", columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    String result = "";

    if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){

        do{

            int timeIn = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("TimeIn"));  
            int timeOut = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("TimeOut"));

            result = (timeIn / 60) + ":" + (timeOut % 60);
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return result;
}

private static class TimesHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private Context mContext;
    private static final String DB_NAME= "db";
    private static final int DB_VERSION= 1;        

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_TIME_TABLE= "CREATE TABLE TimeTable (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,TimeIn INTEGER,TimeOut INTEGER);";


    public TimesHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        try {

            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_TIME_TABLE);                
        }
        catch (SQLiteException exception){

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        try {

            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE TimeTable IF EXISTS;");
            onCreate(db);
        }
        catch (SQLiteException exception){

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: That's not the answer I want. I want to save `Time In`(from the first list) and `Time Out(from last list)`.  into database.

Comment: There are in the same row

Comment: @John your question is not clear.can you read "Time In" when submit button clicked?

Comment: I not yet tried. I want to know how to save the time In and Time Out to one of my table

Comment: You have misunderstood my question. The value inside the listView were actually get from Activity B :)

Comment: Let say this is the code in A.   `btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // sumbit button is clicked
            public void onClick(View arg0) {  TimeRecord.insertTime(a1, W1);     }


                        }


                );`

Comment: how can I indicate that `a1` is **first list** time in, `W1` is **last list** time out ?

Comment: @John Is a1 contains smallest time and w1 contains biggest time?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96647/discussion-between-john-and-javadaskari).

Comment: no. a1 is the first list `time In` value, w1 is the last list `time out` value

Comment: hi, please let me know once you have finished your lunch